# An explanation on COUNT()

Tags: sql

I have been trying to get the grasps of SQL, recently, and I was wondering if you could explain how you could use a `WHERE/AND OR` in a `COUNT()` to return the number of rows with a certain criteria...

Or am I looking into the wrong function? **Any helpful comments are welcome**

EDIT: Heres what I'm working with, I have a simple `SELECT WHERE` query to print out a `profileName` and `profileIcon`. *I am using this as a test to see if `COUNT` works for what I want...* I then want to run a `COUNT` to see how many ROWs are within the criteria.

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM user_settings WHERE Username='" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'");
    while($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
        echo '<tr><th>Current Icon:</th><td><img src="' . $row['ProfileIcon'] . '" /></td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><th>Current Name:</th><td>' . $row['ProfileName'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
$query = $con->query("SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Username='" . $_SESSION['user'] ."' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM user_settings");
    var_dump($query);
```

The `var_dump` produces: `object(mysqli_result)#3 (0) { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you read through [the documentation for COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html). It includes examples with fairly detailed explainations.

An example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pet;
```

this would count all rows found in the `pet` table. You can append a WHERE-statement after this to include a certain criteria.

Comment: So you're saying something like: `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_settings WHERE Username='" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'"` should work?

Comment: Yes. That statement will return the number of rows where Username is matching the value of $_SESSION['user'].

Comment: I just tested your code with a table with 1 row in it with "x" criteria, it returns `object(mysqli_result)#3 (0) { }` so for some reason it isn't counting the row...

Comment: What you got is a mysqli_result object. That is expected. `echo mysql_result($result, 0);` would give you the number given that the returned value is stored in a variable called `$result`.

Comment: when using `echo mysql_result($query, 0);` I get the following error: `Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

Comment: @user3352340 my bad. You're using mysqli, which is preferred. See http://se1.php.net/mysqli_num_rows. Doing `$query->num_rows` should give you the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

For a "conditional" `COUNT`, you can use a `CASE` expression and `SUM`, e.g.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnA = 'Bob' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

will count the number of rows where `ColumnA` is `Bob`, but will include all rows (whether they have `Bob` or not) in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select x, count(*)
from y
where x = ? 
group by x
having count(*) > ?
order by x
```

The having clause is optional.